# remove text post clicking the button

Tags: r

below is my reprex. Post clicking the upload button, the text appears. Upon clicking the clear button the text should go off. Wanted to check the way to do this. Can anyone help me here

````
---
title: "Untitled"
runtime : shiny
output: 
  flexdashboard::flex_dashboard:
    orientation: columns
    vertical_layout: fill
---

```{r setup, include=FALSE}
library(flexdashboard)
code <- "This is code"
```

Column {data-width=650}
-----------------------------------------------------------------------

### Chart A

```{r}
actionButton("upload","Upload",width = 150)
actionButton("clear_upload","Clear",width = 150)
verbatimTextOutput("code")
   get_code <- eventReactive(input$upload,{
     code
   })

   output$code <- renderPrint(
     get_code()
   )
```
````

Answer (score 0):

If I've correctly understood your problem, you may use the the `observeEvent` statement:

````
---
title: "Untitled"
runtime : shiny
output: 
    flexdashboard::flex_dashboard:
    orientation: columns
vertical_layout: fill
---

```{r setup, include=FALSE}
library(flexdashboard)
code <- "This is code"
```

Column {data-width=650}
-----------------------------------------------------------------------

### Chart A

```{r}
actionButton("upload","Upload",width = 150)
actionButton("clear_upload","Clear",width = 150)
verbatimTextOutput("code")

 get_code <- eventReactive(input$upload,{
     code
   })

observeEvent(input$upload, {output$code <- renderPrint(get_code())})
observeEvent(input$clear_upload, {output$code <- renderPrint("")})
```
````